# No computer is booting from my pendrive

Tags: boot, lubuntu, usb-drive

I had created a live bootable usb with lubuntu. But my computer doesn't boot from it. In fact no computer is booting from it. I tried booting with puppy linux and ubuntu, but to no avail. I think the problem is with my pendrive, since no computer is booting from it. I'd like to know how to make it bootable.

Comment: How *exactly* have you created the USB? *With Lubuntu* says nothing. What tool have you used and how?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed in my PC. I downloaded lubuntu 17.10 image file and created a live USB using unetbootin. Everything went fine until then. But when I try to boot my computer from my USB, it doesn't work. I tried to install lubuntu in an another computer with the same usb but the screen simply goes blank and does nothing. I did the same procedure with xenialpup but it's not working. I tried to format the USB as ntfs and fat32 and repeated the procedure but the result is same. If there's a problem with my USB if like to fix it. Has this problem been encountered before?

Comment: Use MKUSB instead.

Comment: OK, I tried that. But the problem persists. I have also tried using 'usb installer.' They create the live usb, but it just won't work. I just created a live usb using an another pendrive and it works fine. Now, I'm pretty sure the problem is with my pendrive. I can install Lubuntu using my other pendrive, but I'd really like to know what the problem really is.

Comment: The problem is hardware (some sticks simply can't be used for that purpose or are defective) and as such, off topic here.

Comment: So, is there any way by which I can remove these defects?

Comment: Again, some sticks just don't work as bootable devices (or don't work with all PCs), nothing to do about it. And neither if defective fort obvious reasons. Good bye and good luck.

Comment: Did you [check the hash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) of the file you downloaded?